# Is there a way to jump within a word using option with arrow keys in iterm2

Tags: keyboard, mac, shortcut, iterm, zsh

> What is the issue?

I have been using the `⌥ + →` & `⌥ + ←` shortcuts to `navigate between words`, along with `⌘ + →` & `⌘ + ←` shortcuts to `navigate to the end / beginning of the line` in `iTerm2`. It works fine, till I need to navigate within a string as described below.

**I need to move to the last `/` just after the `zsh-users` term, on pressing `⌥ + ←`, and to its previous one (the one after `github.com`), on pressing it again.**

[image: First Image]

But as you can see from the image below, `iTerm2` directly sends me to the `:` after `https`, when I press `⌥ + ←` once. How is it taking `:` as a boundary character but not `/`?
[image: Second Image]

And to the start of the url, if I press it again.
[image: Third Image]

---

> Relevant details of my machine and iTerm2
>
> macOS version: `macOS Monterey 12.6.6`
>
> iTerm2 version: `Build 3.4.20`
>
> `iTerm2` > `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Keys` > `Key Mappings` > **`Send ^[b`** is set as **`⌥ ←`**
>
> `iTerm2` > `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Keys` > `Key Mappings` > **`Send ^[f`** is set as **`⌥ →`**

I have searched a lot for this, but unable to get any source / lead for it. I only get the links that show how to move between words, which is already in use on my machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: iTerm doesn't.  The shell you are using does, it is the one implementing the line editor.  Your shell defines what it considers "words"  and separators between them.  A quick search finds https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721412/proper-way-of-setting-word-separators-in-zsh

Comment: Yes! This helped me get the desired result.

Comment: @MarcWilson : Right, but if zsh is set to _emacs_ mode (the OP does not say, but from the question, it seems to me the most likely setup), "word left" is defined as either Meta-b or alternatively Meta-<cursor left>. Now on a Mac, the Meta Key is the _apple key_ (⌘), and AFIK, key combinations with this key are often intercepted by the OS or the application. Therefore it might well be that we have to do some configurations in iTerm or even the system preferences, to make this work. On my Macbook, for instane, Meta-b does not have any effect in iTerm with zsh.

Comment: @user1934428 On a Mac keyboard, Meta is typically the Option key, not Cmd.

Comment: @MarcWilson : Interesting! I googled my (wrong) information from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_metakey.asp) site! I think I will report the error to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the desired result by going through the things pointed out in the link that [Marc Wilson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/89967/marc-wilson) commented to my question.

I set the `WORDCHARS` variable to be `*_-.[]~;!$%^(){}<>`, which by default is set to `*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>` (removed `?`, `=`, `/`, `&`, `#` from the default value).

By `set the WORDCHARS variable`, I mean to have the following lines in my `.zshrc` file.

```bash
# ...
export WORDCHARS='*_-.[]~;!$%^(){}<>'
autoload -Uz select-word-style
select-word-style normal
# ...
```

This solved my issue.

---

#### EDIT: Adding the image of my preferences to show that I have set the Keybinding preset to `Natural Text Editting`.

[image]

Comment: After these changes, which key combination did you use to do a "word left"?

Comment: @user1934428, I used the `⌥ ←` combination, as mentioned in the original question.

Comment: This would be "Option-<cursor left>. It seems that this generates and ESC-D on my platform. Do you know by chance, according to which rule this mapping is performed? If not, I will maybe start a new question on this topic.

Comment: I just checked, it might be because of your key mappings preset.

Change the value to `Natural Text Editting`. You can find it in `iTerm2 Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Keys` > `Key Mappings`. See below the list, there is a `Presets...`. Change that to `Natural Text Editting`.

Comment: Under "Presets" is only "Factory Default" ...  :-(

Comment: I will update the answer above to show you what is there on my iTerm2 preferences. Maybe you are on an older version of it ? I have given my iTerm2's version in the Question.

Comment: I have iTerm 3.4.20 on MacOS 12.6.5. Thanks for going through all the trouble.

Comment: Ah、I see: You have specifics Keymappings to Esc b. I'm missing those!

Comment: @user1934428, There you go. I just added the image. Hope it helps.

Comment: It does. Now it works. Had to do a bit more: In my profile-specific settings, those two option keys were overridden, and when I removed those definitions, I suddenly got also the _Natural Text Editing_ option for the preset!

Comment: That's Great! 